# Generics error syntax Java 1.7 on generics function

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors, syntax-error

Using Java 1.7 compiler, it is interesting to note that the syntax accepted to call generic functions is very particular.  It forces you to use `this` to refer to the generic function.

For example for a function defined as:

```
private <T> Object genericFunction(T t){
    //function code
}
```

When referring to it, the following is gives a syntax error:

```
Object o = <ClassName>genericFunction(ClassName t);
```

While the following is accepted:

```
Object o = this.<ClassName>genericFunction(ClassName t);
```

Why is this so? Shouldn't it take both of them?

Comment: Probably because it's be harder to parse, since it looks like a comparison.

Comment: Why are you providing a type witness at all?

Comment: yes it's pretty annoying. there must have been some technical difficulties. and the benefit is probably not great since in most cases the types would be inferred.

Comment: Why do you say it's required? I'm able to call a generic function with the 1.7 compiler as follows: Object o = genericFunction(s) where s is a String and genericFunction is defined as you did in your example.

Comment: But if you use the generics witness in the function call it will not let you place it in front of it unless you have an expression followed by a `.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's required by the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12).

> MethodInvocation:
>
> - MethodName ( [ArgumentList] )
> - TypeName . [TypeArguments] Identifier ( [ArgumentList] )
> - ExpressionName . [TypeArguments] Identifier ( [ArgumentList] )
> - Primary . [TypeArguments] Identifier ( [ArgumentList] )
> - super . [TypeArguments] Identifier ( [ArgumentList] )
> - TypeName . super . [TypeArguments] Identifier ( [ArgumentList] )

The `TypeArguments` element always has to come after some expression followed by a `.`. It cannot preceded a simple method name.

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice if it wasn't required?

Comment: @JadieldeArmas It doesn't bother me. You rarely need to provide it anyway (at least since Java 8).

Comment: @JadieldeArmas Why is the `<ClassName>` required *at all*? It should be inferred from the parameter.

Comment: @chrylis: you are right, in my example the witness is not needed.

Comment: But I wish that Java would let me write functions where the definition would be `private <T> Object genericFunction()`, and then I could get the type of parameter <T> at run time and do something with it inside the function.

Comment: @JadieldeArmas C# is your best bet.

Comment: The only way I can manage to do it is to pass the Class type as a parameter to the function, defining the function as: `<T> Object genericFunction(Class<T> klassType)`